# Where to find charts plug-in like this?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

highcharts would fit perfectly if not for one "but". The strip chart goes behind the axis. The line graph is beyond the axis numbers(50, 100, 150, 200). Watched others but have not found where you can easily stylize the behavior of the graph by accessing its axis

[chart like this](http://librifolio.ru/dashboard.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply disable margins for chart, then play with `yAxis.offset` to move labels to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/Ywr3L/33/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
        offset: -120   
    },
    series: [{
        data: [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2 , 1, 2, 3, 4],
        type: 'areaspline'
    }]
});
```

Note: without extra coding you can't start series shape before starting of gridlines.

Comment: First, make sure you are not using categories. Then set `xAxis.minPadding = 0`.

Comment: Ok, from the left its all right, but from the right offset a few pixels like this http://jsfiddle.net/xtywajeh/ (by xAxis.minPadding = 0). How I can fix it? And how to set the indent or width for the grid line? I don't want to make it the full width.

Comment: For right side use `xAxis.maxPadding`. For gridlines, see 'note' in the answer.